# TypeError: object() takes no parameters when creating an object

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, indentation

So first of all, I know there is a bunch of answers here already relating this question, but I couldn't find the right one for my problem. When trying to create an object i basically just get this error. If any answers, thanks in advice.

Here's my code:

```
class Human:
    __name = None
    __height = 0

def __init__(self, name, height):
    self.__name = name
    self.__height = height

def set_name(self, name):
    self.__name = name

def get_name(self):
    return self.__name

def set_height(self, height):
    self.__height = height

def get_height(self):
    return self.__height

def get_type(self):
    print('Human')

def toString(self):
    return '{} is {} cm tall.'.format(self.__name,
                                      self.__height)

person = Human('Corey', 180)
```

Comment: Is this your actually formatting? If so, you need to indent all your methods under the class. Also, this is very much *not* how you should be writing classes in Python. Do **not use getters and setters** and do **not** use double-underscore name-mangling unless you need it, which I'm pretty sure you don't.

Comment: Yes, that error is most likely because your code is not indented properly.

Comment: Oh, thanks guys. Everything works properly now. Will keep that in mind from now on tho. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 4):

### Most common cause:  misspelled __init__()

The usual cause of this error is that the *__init__()* method has been misspelled, usually by forgetting one of the two leading or trailing underscores:

```
>>> class A:
        def __init_(self, x, y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

>>> A(10, 20)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#33>", line 1, in <module>
    A(10, 20)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

### Less common cause:  mis-indentiation

The other cause is mis-indentation where the *__init__()* method is not indented to be inside of the class definition:

```
>>> class B:
        """Example class"""

>>> def __init__(self, p, q):
        self.p = p
        self.q = q

>>> B(30, 40)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#41>", line 1, in <module>
    B(30, 40)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Comment: Things seem to be written out properly. I copy pasted the code, and the error was replicated with the code unindented. Tabbing everything in to place resolved everything.

Comment: @idjaw Amended the answer to include the second mostly likely cause.

Answer (score -1):

Your class declaration has to be

```
class Human(object):
```

Comment: That is not the problem with this code. Furthermore, they are using Python 3, which does not need to inherit from `object` anymore.

Comment: The Question has a Python-3.x tag.