# Why am I getting an error in Python like Dog() takes no arguments?

Tags: python, python-class

Why am I getting an error in Python like `Dog()` takes no arguments?

```
class Dog:
    def _init_(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
my_dog = Dog('Willie', 6)
print(f"my dog's name is {my_dog.name}.")
print(f"my dog is {my_dog.age} years old.")
```

Comment: `def _init_(self, name, age)` => `def __init__(self, name, age):`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: object() takes no parameters when creating an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250605/typeerror-object-takes-no-parameters-when-creating-an-object)

Comment: Please have a closer look at the duplicate link, and my code above - use a double underscore `__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `__init__` not `_init_`, so change the following line:

```
    def _init_(self, name, age)
```

To:

```
    def _init_(self, name, age):
```

*P.S. you need a colon at the end of the line.*

Comment: Please look at the duplicate link which explains the error correctly.. or my comments above

Comment: *"The usual cause of this error is that the __init__() method has been misspelled, usually by forgetting one of the two leading or trailing underscores:"* - from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45250667/14722562) answer.