# Why the instance variables in Constructor not displayed in output?

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Employee:
    def __int__(self):
        self.eno=100
        self.ename='Hari'
        self.esal=10000
e=Employee()
print(e.__dict__)
```

Comment: You misspelled `__init__` as `__int__`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: object() takes no parameters when creating an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250605/typeerror-object-takes-no-parameters-when-creating-an-object)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45250667/14722562) answer in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

change `def __int__(self):` to `def __init__(self):`.